# \newtheoremstyle for use in various latex documents

Tags: package-writing

Have made a number of `\newtheoremstyle` in my document.  It is great, but would like my other documents to use them, rather than having to redefine them for every document I produce.  Would I need to write something similar to `\usepackage` ?

Comment: Yes, you can create a super simple `sty` file, or alternatively just a tex file with these definitions and `\input` it in your documents.

Comment: Are there any other types of configuration files in latex apart from `sty` files?

Comment: As far as I know, if you use `\input` to put contents into preamble, extension name does not matter. It can be anything. Just read the file content.